# Excel VBA - Using lookup formula for a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use lookup function with VBA for a dynamic range. The figure below is an example of few lines of data that I am trying to test with. The top two rows are my header rows that represent range of ‘heights’ for each ‘year’ of available data.

The data in black font is my row data. From where with code I am getting the red font data which are just the max values (i.e. the largest values) for each height for all available years for that height. Now I am also trying to find the year of the max value with the lookup function in VBA and paste to the right hand cells as shown in blue font in Figure 1. I can do this for a selected range using the following code and produce the output as shown in Figure 1 but I could not logically think of how to do this for a dynamic range.

My problem is that my row data that is highlighted in black is dynamic range and data highlighted in red also will be of a dynamic range depending of number of ‘heights’. So I am struggling to think of a logical way of setting the two ranges of black and red texts and find the year of the maximum value as shown in blue colour in figure 1. I would be greatful if someone could give me some advise on how I could approach to this problem. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Lookup()
         Range("K3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LOOKUP(RC[-3],RC[-10]:RC[-4],R[-1]C[-10]:R[-1]C[-4])"
        Range("K3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(RC[-3],RC1:RC7,R2C1:R2C7)"
    Range("K3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K3:M3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("K3:M3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K3:M5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("K3:M5").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into "Normalization"?  This kind of layout seems like it would have problems over time, having to insert columns.  With repeating column names.  You might have to just break down and make separate sheets for each year with the same layout.  Then run the code over the matching cell address on a different sheet.  Instead of having to keep track of how many columns to shift, as the years grow, this will get ugly.

Comment: I actually have each height and year max in seperate sheets from where I am creating this table (the black font section). than I am running a code that calculates the red fonts (i.e. the max values).  I have just tried to replace the max values with year  but its not working for me. Would you like me to share the codes that I am creating the max values? perhaps you could advise how can I just replace them with year? thanks

Comment: Is the problem happening when you have to add another year and are trying to use the same sheet to recalculate the max? thus needing to change the color format?

Comment: I have added the code for the red section (i.e. the max values). Is there any way I could replace .value section at the end to add the year instead of max? I can then try to create ahoter worksheet with just year.

Comment: I just have a hard time grasping how to accomplish what you want with the table layout that way.  If you'll entertain changing the layout slightly consider the answer below.

Comment: thats exaclt what I was missing, I could just change my table layout and get to what I am looking for! thanks a lot for your guidence and the asnwer below! which is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you have going, but since I already worked it up and Tested it.  Working, it delivers the results you wanted and allows for more years to be input later.

```
Private Sub FilterMax()

Dim max10 As Single
Dim max20 As Single
Dim max30 As Single

Dim max10Year As Long
Dim max20Year As Long
Dim max30Year As Long

Dim row As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Dim firstYear As Long
Dim lastYear As Long
Dim year As Long

Dim sheet As String

lastRow = Sheets("MaxValues").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

'You might want to put an input box up or just manually set this.
firstYear = 2012
lastYear = 2014

For row = 2 To lastRow
'reset max for each DataRow
max10 = 0
max10Year = 0
max20 = 0
max20Year = 0
max30 = 0
max30Year = 0

    For year = firstYear To lastYear

    sheet = CStr(year)
    'Max10
    If Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, 2) > max10 Then
        max10 = Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, 2)
        max10Year = Sheets(sheet).Range("G1")
    End If
    'Max20
    If Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, 3) > max20 Then
        max20 = Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, 3)
        max20Year = Sheets(sheet).Range("G1")
    End If
    'Max30
    If Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, 4) > max30 Then
        max30 = Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, 4)
        max30Year = Sheets(sheet).Range("G1")
    End If

    Next year

    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 2).Value = max10
    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 2).Font.Color = vbRed

    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 3).Value = max10Year
    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 3).Font.Color = vbBlue

    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 4).Value = max20
    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 4).Font.Color = vbRed

    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 5).Value = max20Year
    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 5).Font.Color = vbBlue

    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 6).Value = max30
    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 6).Font.Color = vbRed

    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 7).Value = max30Year
    Sheets("MaxValues").Cells(row, 7).Font.Color = vbBlue

Next row

End Sub
```

[image: MaxValues]
[image: 2012]
[image: 2013]
[image: 2014]

Comment: that’s brilliant, you just gave me a complete new set of simple ideas of how I could approach my entire result calculation! Thanks a Lot!